# php code to send email using find function in forloop

Tags: php, cakephp

I have startdate and end date in my table like below.

startdate = 2016-01-01

Enddate = 2016-06-20

Now i want to send email automatically before 1 month from end date.

everything is working fine...email is also sending..

But my problem is i want to send email to multiple users if there are 2 rows match in table with my conditions then email is gone to both the users.

But my code only send email to only single users..not all users.
I want email is gone to all users one by one.

```
public function certificateExpired()
    {
       $this->autoRender = False;
       $this->loadModel('Certificate');
       $data = $this->Certificate->find("all", array(
            'recursive' => -1, // should be used with joins     
            'fields' => array('User.*', 'Certificate.*'),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'users',
                        'alias' => 'User',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array('User.id = Certificate.user_id')
                    )
                ),
                'conditions' => array('Certificate.is_expirable' => 1,'Certificate.status' => 1)
        ));    
        foreach ($data as $row) {       
           $currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
           $date = $row['Certificate']['end_date'];
           $newdate = strtotime($date .' -1 months');
           $enddate = date('Y-m-d', $newdate);
           if ($currentdate >= $enddate) {
            //For sending email
            $data['email'] = $row['User']['email'];
            $data['name'] = $row['User']['name'];
            $data['document_name'] = $row['Certificate']['name'];
            $data['templateid'] = 19;  
            $send_mail = $this->EmailFunctions->certificateExpiredTemplate($data); 
             if ($send_mail) {
              $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Dashboards', 'action' => 'shipperDashboard'));
              }     
           }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: put your redirect outside of foreach loop

Comment: Just put the `$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Dashboards', 'action' => 'shipperDashboard'));` outside the foreach loop

Comment: okay..i am testing...

Comment: thanks you ..its working......

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($data as $row) {       
           $currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
           $date = $row['Certificate']['end_date'];
           $newdate = strtotime($date .' -1 months');
           $enddate = date('Y-m-d', $newdate);
           if ($currentdate >= $enddate) {
            //For sending email
            $data['email'] = $row['User']['email'];
            $data['name'] = $row['User']['name'];
            $data['document_name'] = $row['Certificate']['name'];
            $data['templateid'] = 19;  
            $send_mail = $this->EmailFunctions->certificateExpiredTemplate($data);    
           }
}

$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Dashboards', 'action' => 'shipperDashboard'));
```

Change the foreach loop as above.